# change a parent class based on children information

Tags: python, css, selenium

I just started using selenium and came accross this website: https://equi.generali.fr/devis-en-ligne-proprietaire-d-un-equide

there are these buttons:

[image]

with the following elements:

[image]

What I am having issues with is that both these buttons have the same id name. And as far as can tell I cannot just use the click function from selenium. I have to change from "btn" to "btn active" to activate the buttons.

So with this information how could I change the div class="btn" to div class="btn active" based on the children information. Or is there an easier way I am not seeing?

My code until this point:

```
btn_cookie = driver.find_element_by_id('popin_tc_privacy_button')
btn_cookie.click()

input_year = driver.find_element_by_id('quote_equine_owner_equineBirthYear')

input_gear = driver.find_element_by_id('quote_equine_owner_equineValue')

input_rcpe_yes = driver.find_element_by_id('quote_equine_owner_hasSubscribedRcpe_0')
input_rcpe_no = driver.find_element_by_id('quote_equine_owner_hasSubscribedRcpe_1')

input_sub_yes = driver.find_element_by_id('quote_equine_owner_subscribeVeterinaryCharge_0')
input_sub_no = driver.find_element_by_id('quote_equine_owner_subscribeVeterinaryCharge_1')

options_year = []
for option in input_year.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    options_year.append(option.get_attribute("value"))

options_gear = []
for option in input_gear.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    options_gear.append(option.get_attribute("value"))

yes_no = ['yes','no']
containers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="btn-group  btn-group-toggle row mx-auto align-items-center justify-content-center"]')
print(containers)

for item in containers:
    print(item)

for year in options_year:
    input_year.send_keys(year)
    time.sleep(2)
    if int(year) > 2000:
        for price in options_gear:
            input_gear.send_keys(price)
            time.sleep(2)
```

I am trying to loop through this information to get the prices at the end and store them.

Thanks.

Comment: I can’t see that they have the same id, could you point out where the repetition of id is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

The only id that differs in the buttons is in a child branch so:

```
#find child element
input_rcpe_yes = driver.find_element_by_id('quote_equine_owner_hasSubscribedRcpe_0')
input_rcpe_no = driver.find_element_by_id('quote_equine_owner_hasSubscribedRcpe_1')
#go up two steps to parent element
btn_yes_1 = input_rcpe_yes.find_element_by_xpath('./../..')
btn_no_1 = input_rcpe_no.find_element_by_xpath('./../..')
#change parent element to active or non active
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class', 'btn')", btn_yes_1)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class', 'btn active')", btn_no_1)
```